# Unbound checkbox in continuous form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm beating a dead horse here, but I still haven't found the answer I am looking for. I am throwing together an Access Database that deals with lockout procedures for our various machines at work. I have a continuous form setup so that it dynamically populates based on various complex/machine criteria. Since only portions of the machines need to be locked out at a given time, it is necessary to select the various devices from the list that was populated dynamically. When users select the various devices that they wish to lockout, they will then be able to automatically print tags for the selected devices. Which is where the unbound checkbox conundrum comes in... Yay!!!

Since it is possible for multiple users to be using the database at a given time, I don't believe that binding the checkbox to a yes/no selection within my table is the correct path to take. This is due to the fact that having multiple users picking various devices would result in additional/unnecessary tags being printed out to each user. I know that it's possible to have an unbound checkbox within a continuous form, but I have not come across any sample code that has this functionality.

If there is another path that I can take, please offer any suggestions as I am an Access novice, and am open to new ideas.

**EDIT**
I should mention that the database will reside within Citrix. I am not sure if this affect anything, but its worth mentioning at least.

Comment: "I know that it's possible to have an unbound checkbox within a continuous form..." An unbound checkbox in continuous form is pointless as when you check it, all the records get checked. As far as I know there is no workaround.

Comment: I know that there is a work around using VBA, unfortunately the links to the example databases are all broken and I am not well versed enough with VBA or Access...

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you are using a client server setting, where the application file resides on a local machine. (Or on a local instance in the case of RDP / Citrix)

In that case, you can have a local table to save the checkbox information without causing any conflicts between users.

You will be using a bound checkbox, so problem solved.

Comment: That's a good point that I hadn't thought of. Looks like I'll be performing a few tests to see if it works as desired. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: If it's a good point, perhaps vote it up as a useful answer :)