# Is there any way to select all or some row of records and then hit a command button that will effect the row of records the same way?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2016

I have a continuous form that contains a varying number of records. Typically it doesn't exceed 100 but it can. Below is the form showing a few row of records. I was wondering if its possible to select a few or all of the records and after selecting them, I click a command button that will run its code accordingly with each record selected.

[Continous Form Displaying a few rows of records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMlwM.png)

Comment: Insert an unbound checkbox and process based on the checkbox

Comment: @dbmitch Could you explain a little more?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to have unbound checkboxes on an access continuous form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63908153/how-to-have-unbound-checkboxes-on-an-access-continuous-form)

Answer (score 0):

The most easy way is to add a check box column to the table. However, in a multi-user environment, this can fall apart. But, the idea is you check off the rows, and then hit a button. That button can process all records with "ToProcess = True" and then when done, it un-sets those records. Since the process would be limited to the one sub form dataset, then this can even work quite well in a multi-user environment, since those sub-forms records are un-likely to be open/viewed at the same time by others.

So, just add a true/false column to the sub form table, and display. The user can check box which rows to operation against. You thus limit the query to the sub form records +

Comment: This database will be multi-user but only a select few will be to do this procedure.

Comment: If simultaneous users are running the same process and requesting all records that are True, need additional filter criteria than just "ToProcess=True" in order to, hopefully, prevent conflicts. Same goes for updating records to remove the True status. Assumes simultaneous users will not ever want any of the same records.

Comment: But we assume that the data set is limited by the sub form, right? So it not the whole table then? I mean, we don't expect two users to pull up the same form, and same sub form of records? How is the sub form filtered? If it is filter by parent form, then this should be fine. Since then your process loop ONLY works on sub form records + the one checked column "to process". After the loop, you then un-check (set to false) that process column - this should be ok as long as the data is limited to the one sub form.  I mean, if two users are on the same form+sub form, then thats problem regardless

Comment: This wil all come done to how the sub-form data filter was made in first place. I don't see a problem unless the sub form is filtered in some way not related to parent form.

Comment: However, you can ALSO try this idea by me outlined here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63908153/how-to-have-unbound-checkboxes-on-an-access-continuous-form

Comment: In above, I use un-bound check boxes, so it would not matter for multi-user. its a bit more complex, but can work well for your needs. It does NOT require you add a column to the table, and you can still select as many rows as you want.